# Latest block number and its transactions from etherchain.org

Tags: ether, etherscan

I am trying to get the latest block information such as `latest block number` and all its `transactions details` such as `Tx hash, gas price, gas used, timestamp` etc., from `etherchain.org`. I know `Etherscan` has their API for such things, but I also need to see whether `Etherchain` have those.

Is there such `etherchain api` to get these information? Etherchain has `https://etherchain.org/api/basic_stats` to get some stats, and `https://www.etherchain.org/api/gasPriceOracle` to get gas price but none of them provides the latest block  and its information.

Anyone have any idea on this? Or any other suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Etherchain.org website has pages that show a list of recent blocks and transactions. Looking under the hood, it looks like they use a REST API which fetches the latest blocks and transactions. Limiting the length parameter in the API call should give you the latest block and latest transaction.

Blocks: https://etherchain.org/blocks/data?draw=1&start=0&length=0

```
{
    "draw": "1",
    "recordsTotal": 10282670,
    "recordsFiltered": 10282670,
    "data": [{
            "number": "<a href='/block/10282670'>10282670</a>",
            "hash": "<a href='/block/098cf21be9359089796e8eb5dba7bb3ec256205212bd9a255444cdd71bc1eb8a'>0x098cf21be935908...</a>",
            "difficulty": "2.283 T",
            "miner": "<a href='/account/04668ec2f57cc15c381b461b9fedab5d451c8f7f'>✔ zhizhu (0x0466...)</a>",
            "gasused": "0",
            "gaslimit": "9985355",
            "time": "a few seconds ago",
            "tx_count": 0,
            "uncle_count": 0,
            "blocktime": "37s",
            "usage": "0 % (0 of 9,985,355)"
        }
    ]
}
```

Transactions: https://etherchain.org/txs/data?draw=1&start=0&length=1

```
{
    "draw": null,
    "recordsTotal": 500000,
    "recordsFiltered": 500000,
    "data": [{
            "blocknumber": "<a href='/block/10282640'>10282640</a>",
            "parenthash": "<a href='/tx/70e9e8ada1b047cd33d2695c867e1af209dcab929d887bbd1882b5b08fd36968'>0x70e9e8ada1...</a>",
            "from": "<a href='/account/ffbfdb803d38d794b5785ee0ac09f83b429d11b5'>0xFFbFDb803D38D...</a>",
            "to": "<a href='/account/693c188e40f760ecf00d2946ef45260b84fbc43e'>0x693c188E40F76...</a>",
            "value": "0 ETH",
            "gasused": "110039",
            "gasprice": "165.1 GWei",
            "time": "a minute ago",
            "type": "<div class=\"text-capitalize\">tx</div>",
            "invokescontract": true,
            "fee": "0.01817 ETH"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @StephenS, this is really helpful, how can I get all transaction records from a specific block, say blockNumber=10282670 using API?

Comment: @temp I couldn't find an API which gives this, Etherchain does have a page though which gives you a list of transactions for a specific block (https://etherchain.org/block/10288434). Unfortunately the data shown in the page is server-side rendered, so your best bet here would be to parse through the HTML if your'e desperate enough....